# I haven't mentioned spring.web.2.5.6 but still its downloading this jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

when i am running mvn -package my project is downloading spring.web.2.5.6 but I haven't mentioed that in my pom.xml.
this is my pom-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nated.app.migration</groupId>
<artifactId>nated</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>nated Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logger.version>1.2.16</logger.version>
    <quartz.version>1.5.1</quartz.version>
    <tiles.version>2.2.1</tiles.version>
    <ldap.version>4.3</ldap.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring dependency starts -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring dependency Ends -->
    <!-- MySQL Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.novell.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>jldap</artifactId>
        <version>${ldap.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>nated</finalName>
    <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any one suggest why this happening?it would be a great help.I have tried many way but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: And this? ` <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>`?

Comment: Maybe it is a dependecy of one  of the artifacts. use `mvn dependency:tree` to find it out.

Comment: but I have mentioned 3.1.1.release and its downloading 3.1.1 and also 2.5.6,why its downloading 2.5.6

Comment: @Jens I used that command but when i am running that command its start downloading many jars ,could understand

Comment: @EvanKnowles wrong version. `<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId><version>${spring.version}</version>
`

Comment: @Rahulray Thats jars wich mvn needs to execute the command. it is ok.

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>  <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>this two line says that download 3.1.1version of jar but why it downloading both 3.1.1 and 2.5.6 version.this is the question

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the POM you have provided.  `mvn dependency:tree` [does not show spring-web-2.5.6](http://pastebin.com/2C8iuFmi).  After running `mvn clean package`, the `target/nated/WEB-INF/lib` folder [does not contain](http://pastebin.com/nizDJvCn) spring-web-2.5.6 JAR either.

Comment: @Rahulray have you tried to clean and rebuild your package?